# Change <link href="#"> with click

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink, href

I want to make "intro" page where you can choose two different colors for the template.

My question is: is there a way to do this without creating new .html files with changed style?

is there a way, where you can change  with click and that to lead you to index.html? (also, if this is possible, how to apply this to all .html documents)

Thanks!

Comment: What does that have to do with the title of the question?

Comment: The title describes the answer .. 

`$("#urlLinkID").attr("href", "theme1.css");`

Comment: Are you making static html pages, using some dynamic technology like php or ruby-on-rails, or are you using a high level platform like wordpress or mediawiki?

Comment: @Volodya Everything? He's asking how to dynamically alter the href of a `link` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just select the link and change its href:

```
$('link[rel=stylesheet]').attr('href', 'my-other-sheet.css');
```

If you have multiple stylesheet include tags, you'll need to select by some other criteria like `id`.

Comment: hey, Thanks for the answer..

but, this function need to perform in another document and to be called from "intro.html" ...

Comment: You can't do that. You can't access anything from another document.